# Mobile DJI SDK during simulation stops flying

Tags: dji-sdk

Probably something silly, was working before, a year ago... Could be a clue. The hardware has not changed(Mavic 2), and the SDK version niether 4.14-trial1.

Starting the simulator programmatically (Simulator simulator = flightController.getSimulator();) then sending virtual stick data to the aircraft, it moves forward for a while, about 15 seconds, then just slows down to a stop for no apparent reason. Does any one have a clue?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

The maximum flight radius is set and somehow not modifiable(500 from the callback).

But the actual maximum radius is 100 metres! Setting the maximum flight radius enabled off has no effect, and trying to set the flight radius results in a 'Param illegal' error.

So not solved, but the cause is known, seemingly. Actually setting any integer over 99 in the setMaxFlightRadius fails.

How to set the maximum flight radius in SDK 4.14.1?